# Call to a member function increment() on null

Tags: laravel, content-management-system, crud

everything work fine when i call post use $id,
since i change to $slug, it show error

> Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError
>   (E_ERROR) Call to a member function increment() on null

my controller after i change $id to slug

```
public function showpost($slug)
{
    $post = Post::published()
    ->where('slug', '=', $slug)->first();

    $post->increment('view_count');

    return view("blog.showpost", compact('post'));
}
```

here is blade file

```
<div class="block-heading-1">
   <span class="text-muted mb-3 mt-5">
        <i class="fa fa-clock-o fa-lg"></i>&nbsp{{ $post->date }}
        <i class="fa fa-eye fa-lg"></i>{{ $post->view_count }}
        <i class="fa fa-comments-o fa-lg"></i>&nbsp{{ $post->comments->count() }}
   </span>
        <h1 class="mb-4" style="font-size: 20px; padding-top: 15px; margin-bottom: 0px; pad"> 
            {{ $post->title }}
       </h1>
</div>
```

how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

if slug is not exist eloquent return null so when post is null, you do not increment on null model. Please be sure slug is exist.

Comment: did you mean exist on the table?

Comment: yes, Test it with this id. find with id and toArray and print_r, be sure really your slug exist in your collection. $post = Post::find(1)->toArray(); print_r($post);

Comment: Important tip for your development: please check with "if" after the model get always. And always use in try catch

Comment: slug is exist on the table, and there a value on it.

Comment: is published? Did you check with id in eloquent query?

Comment: $post = Post::find(1)->toArray(); print_r($post); where i shold type this code?

Comment: @kuntet meaning. your code is works very well, another mistake here, please write this code $post = Post::published()->where('id', $idWhichAssociatedYourSlug)->toArray();